Computing surface integral of a plane and being confused of the formula of normal
I want to find the flux out of the plane $x+2y+3z=6$ in the first quadrant where my vector field is $\mathbb{F} = (x,z,0)$. Now I parametrize the plane: $\vec{x} = (6+6t,3s,-2t-2s)$. Now when I follow my notes I have the formula:
$$\iint_S \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{\vec{S}} = \iint_S \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbb{\vec{N}}ds = \iint_S \mathbf{F} \cdot \frac{\vec{x_s} \times \vec{x_s}}{||\vec{x_s} \times \vec{x_s} ||} \cdot ||\vec{x_s} \times \vec{x_s} || ds dt = \iint_S \mathbf{F} \cdot (\vec{x_s} \times \vec{x_s}) ds dt$$
Now, I get $(\vec{x_s} \times \vec{x_s}) = (6,12,18)$
If I follow the formula this I get
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \int_{-1}^{-s} \begin{pmatrix}
6 + 6t \\
-2t - 2s \\
0
\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
6 \\
12 \\
18
\end{pmatrix} \, dt \, ds
 = 6$$
The answer to this is $10$ but I cannot follow where I am going wrong and would appreciate it if someone helped me out as I believe there is something wrong in the way I use the normal as instead of $(6,12,18)$ I could have used $(1,2,3)$ but I don't understand which one would be correct as in the formula the norm of the normal gets cancelled and thus the choice of my normal vector does matter.

First things first. How is the plane oriented?

Next, you need $x_s\times x_t$ (or the negative).

I do calculate $x_s\times x_t$ as $(6,12,18)$.

@TedShifrin what do you mean by the orientation of the plane?

You must be told which direction the outward-pointing normal points (e.g., up or down).

@TedShifrin My question tell me about the flux outwards so I would guess the normal points out or upwards

You cannot guess. You must be told, but this affects just a $\pm$ at the end. Your set-up is completely correct. You made a mistake when you did the integration,

@TedShifrin Thanks a lot for pointing out the calculation error and clarifying my method is correct. Also the sign is $+$.

I made a calculation error.
$$\int_{0}^{1} \left( \int_{-1}^{-s} \left( 6(6 + 6t) + 12(-2t - 2s) \right) dt \right) ds = 10.$$
My method was however correct :)
